# How can I setup permission of Linux char driver?

Tags: linux, char, kernel, driver, device

Folks,
i wrote a char driver for my i2c device. It is working on Android 4.0.3 using Linux kernel 3.0.8.

When I try to access the driver using `ioctl()` with my native Android app. I get a permission denied error.

If I create the device file using the following command I don't get the permission error.

```
mknod /dev/barcodescan c 100 0
```

I don't want to have to manually issue this command all the time but instead that the module does it on startup. I wrote the following code but I get a permission denied error.
How can I setup permission in this code?

```
ret= register_chrdev(MAJOR_NUMBER,"barcode",&fops );

if(ret) {   
   pr_info(KERN_ERR "%s:register chrdev failed\n",__FILE__);    
   return ret;
}

i2c_dev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE,"barcode");

if (IS_ERR(i2c_dev_class)) {        
   ret = PTR_ERR(i2c_dev_class);        
   class_destroy(i2c_dev_class);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are building your own Android image.

In that case, you need to edit [`init.rc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/rootdir/init.rc) to add lines like this to make sure that your device node is automatically created at boot:

```
mknod /dev/barcodescan c 100 0
chown system system /dev/barcodescan
```

You may want to change `system`:`system` to some other account and/or add more permissions with chmod, for example using `chmod 666`, but this is not recommended.